# Customize solr 4.10.3 search results

Tags: solr, lucene

I have found type of document in solr database. Out of those 4, one is general document, second news, third books and fourth poetry. Now I want to query solr so that it should return 10 results. out of those 7 result should be from general documents, 1 from news, 1 from books and 1 from poetry. I am using solr in cloud mode.

Is it possible. if yes then how if not then why ? 
Basically, I want to get all these in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [result grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping). Based on this documentation your request should be

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?wt=json&indent=true&
                 q=you_query_string&group=true&group.field=type&group.limit=7
```

After search you should take seven items from group with general type, and by one item from others groups.